# create new columns using combination of existing columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
test
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  1  3  2  1  6  2
2  2  2  3  2  3  4
3  3  5  5  3  4  1
4  4  7  7  1  2  5
5  5  9  4  3  8  7
6  6  3  1  5  2  6
```

I need to add means of columns in different combinations to new columns in this data frame like column m1 would be rowmeans of column v1 and v5, column m2 would be rowmeans of column v2, v3 ,and v6.

I have m1 as character vector consisting two elements v1 and v5 , similarly other mean column:

```
m1<- c("v1","v5")
m2<- c("v2","v3","v6")
```

I want to generalize this operation as a function, that I can apply other data sets also, where the name of the columns also has to be dynamic. These column names would be taken from another character vector:

```
meancol<-c("m1","m2")
```

Comment: Something along the lines of `lapply(list(m1, m2), function(i) rowMeans(test[i]))`?..and of course you tidy up the result to your liking...

Comment: `test$M1 <- rowMeans(test[m1]); test$M2 <- rowMeans(test[m2])`

Comment: Personally, I don't love building the ability to use a character vector to refer to objects that are character vectors in the environment. It feels too reliant on the environment / prone to possible errors. I would do it manually if you have to do it. As a side note, you will need to decide what you want to do with `meancol` if`m1` and `m2` both have the same column names. Do you want it included twice in the mean calculation, or do you want unique column names?